# can't deploy to real device usr/lib/libxml2.dylib (No such file or directory)

Tags: objective-c, xcode

When i'm trying to build an xcode 7 project on device i get this error (on simulator it's work)

error:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't open file: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.3.sdk/usr/lib/libxml2.dylib (No such file or directory)

I looked in `usr/lib`. i only find `ibxml2.2.dylib`, also in project. i can't find where `libxml2.dylib` it is used.

Comment: In `Project/Build Phases/Link Binary With Libraries`, do you have `libxml2.dylib` or `libxml2.tbd`?

Comment: i have only libxml2.2.dylib , i can't find libxml2.dylib or libxml2.tbd i use xcode 7,3